# Ignore invalid input until the correct character is assigned to a char variable

Tags: c

Before I introduce my problem, I would like to inform you that I am using Notepad++ and Cygwin:

I am trying to write some code in C language so that it will help a user decide a potential top choice between his or her selection of choices for something (like deciding which computer to buy based on the user's preferences) or give guidance while the user tries to come up with some choices to use for determining a potential top choice. The code shown below is incomplete, but I am first trying to make sure that the program will only proceed once a user enters `y`, `n`, `Y`, or `N`:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int  main()
    {
        //This character used for input indicating yes or no.
        char yN = 'a';

        //The following will be used to determine whether the program should help the user decide among certain paths or give the user guidance to do so.
        printf("In the current situation that you have encountered, are you unable to decide between or among a few things? (Y/N)\n");

        //This while loop will ignore invalid input and will "break" once valid input is assigned to the character variable yN
        while(yN != 'y' || yN != 'Y' || yN != 'n' || yN != 'N')
        {
            scanf(" %c", &yN);
        }

        //This will lead to the narrowingPath function.
        if(yN == 'y' || yN == 'Y')
        {
            printf("Good\n");
        }

        //This will lead to the gatheringChoices function.
        else if(yN == 'n' || yN == 'N')
        {
            printf("Hang in there\n");
        }

        //Invalid Input
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid Input\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Unfortunately, the while loop that I used for ignoring invalid input and looking for valid input doesn't work as expected.

Output and Input Attempts:

> ```
> noahertz@CO1313-25 /cygdrive/x/cpre185/NoahErtz/practice6
> $ gcc -o Ertz_Noah_PP_6 Ertz_Noah_PP_6.c -Wall
> noahertz@CO1313-25 /cygdrive/x/cpre185/NoahErtz/practice6
> $ ./Ertz_Noah_PP_6
> In the current situation that you have encountered,are you unable to
> decide between or among a few things? (Y/N)
> y
> Y
> n
> N
>  y
>  Y
>  n
>  N
> noahertz@CO1313-25 /cygdrive/x/cpre185/NoahErtz/practice6
> $
> ```

I cancelled out of the program with Ctrl+C because I wasn't getting anywhere. Here's what happens when I modify the while loop:

```
    //This while loop will ignore invalid input and will "break" once valid input is assigned to the character variable yN
    while(yN != 'y' || yN != 'Y' || yN != 'n' || yN != 'N')
    {
        printf("%c\n", yN);
        scanf(" %c", &yN);
    }
```

Output and Input Attempts:

> ```
> noahertz@CO1313-25 /cygdrive/x/cpre185/NoahErtz/practice6
> $ gcc -o Ertz_Noah_PP_6 Ertz_Noah_PP_6.c -Wall
> noahertz@CO1313-25 /cygdrive/x/cpre185/NoahErtz/practice6
> $ ./Ertz_Noah_PP_6
> In the current situation that you have encountered, are you unable to
> decide between or among a few things? (Y/N)
> a
> y
> y
> Y
> Y
> n
> n
> N
> N
>  y
> y
>  n
> n
>  Y
> Y
>  N
> N
> noahertz@CO1313-25 /cygdrive/x/cpre185/NoahErtz/practice6
> $
> ```

So if yN is being assigned the char as intended, why isn't the program exiting out of the while loop and continuing onto the if and else statements? They work:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int  main()
    {
        //This character used for input indicating yes or no.
        char yN = 'a';
        
        //The following will be used to determine whether the program should help the user decide among certain paths or give the user guidance to do so.
        printf("In the current situation that you have encountered, are you unable to decide between or among a few things? (Y/N)\n");
        scanf(" %c", &yN);

        //This while loop will ignore invalid input and will "break" once valid input is assigned to the character variable yN
        /*while(yN != 'y' || yN != 'Y' || yN != 'n' || yN != 'N')
        {
            printf("%c\n", yN);
            scanf(" %c", &yN);
        }*/

        //This will lead to the narrowingPath function.
        if(yN == 'y' || yN == 'Y')
        {
            printf("Good\n");
        }

        //This will lead to the gatheringChoices function.
        else if(yN == 'n' || yN == 'N')
        {
            printf("Hang in there\n");
        }

        //Invalid Input
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid Input\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Output and input attempts:

> ```
> noahertz@CO1313-25 /cygdrive/x/cpre185/NoahErtz/practice6
> $ gcc -o Ertz_Noah_PP_6 Ertz_Noah_PP_6.c -Wall
> noahertz@CO1313-25 /cygdrive/x/cpre185/NoahErtz/practice6
> $ ./Ertz_Noah_PP_6
> In the current situation that you have encountered, are you unable to
> decide between or among a few things? (Y/N)
> y
> Good
> noahertz@CO1313-25 /cygdrive/x/cpre185/NoahErtz/practice6
> $ ./Ertz_Noah_PP_6
> In the current situation that you have encountered, are you unable to
> decide between or among a few things? (Y/N)
> Y
> Good
> noahertz@CO1313-25 /cygdrive/x/cpre185/NoahErtz/practice6
> $ ./Ertz_Noah_PP_6
> In the current situation that you have encountered, are you unable to
> decide between or among a few things? (Y/N)
> n
> Hang in there
> noahertz@CO1313-25 /cygdrive/x/cpre185/NoahErtz/practice6
> $ ./Ertz_Noah_PP_6
> In the current situation that you have encountered, are you unable to
> decide between or among a few things? (Y/N)
> N
> Hang in there
> noahertz@CO1313-25 /cygdrive/x/cpre185/NoahErtz/practice6
> $ ./Ertz_Noah_PP_6
> In the current situation that you have encountered, are you unable to
> decide between or among a few things? (Y/N)
> a
> Invalid Input
> noahertz@CO1313-25 /cygdrive/x/cpre185/NoahErtz/practice6
> $
> ```

Let me know if you need more information to help me resolve this problem. I look forward to your responses.

Comment: If you enter only `y,Y,n or N` , then when do you think this will be false -`while(yN != 'y' || yN != 'Y' || yN != 'n' || yN != 'N')` ?

Comment: @ameyCU I thought once the user would assign y, Y, n, or N to yN, the condition would be true. Since && was needed, I am now confused with why it works this way. I thought && would be used to make the condition true only when all of the comparisons were true.

Comment: regarding this line: `while(yN != 'y' || yN != 'Y' || yN != 'n' || yN != 'N')`  Lets remember back to high school when working with algebra and boolean logic.  If the user entered 'Y'' then it would stay in the loop because the user entry is not 'y' or 'n' nor 'N'.   Suggest fixing this problem by replacing the current line with: `while(yN != 'y' && yN != 'Y' && yN != 'n' && yN != 'N')

Comment: Remember, back to school and algebra and boolean logic, that when the comparison is 'not'd that the linking operator must be reversed  I.E. when using `!=` then the linking operator must be `&&`, not `||`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`||` needs to be replaced with `&&` as below

```
while(yN != 'y' && yN != 'Y' && yN != 'n' && yN != 'N')
```

As a general rule, whenever same variable is compared against multiple values using the inequality operator `!=`, then there needs to be `&&` in between. Similarly, whenever same variable is compared against multiple values using the equality operator `==`, then there needs to be `||` in between.

Comment: This worked! But now, why? Shouldn't || be used when only one of the conditions need to be true. I thought that && would be used when all of the conditions need to be true, and if one isn't, it would be false. Please help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: @NAE, here it is not that one of the conditions needs to be true, but all the conditions needs to be true. Here you are checking that the variable does not take "all" of the values you listed.

Comment: @user1969104 I now see how && works in this case, but I don't understand why || didn't work. Shouldn't they both work with either the inequality operator or the equality operator? What's the reasoning behind this? For example: if a user made the input y and II was used, shouldn't y make yN != 'y' false, and everything else is ignored, causing the program to break out of the while loop?

Comment: @NAE: You have to think a bit carefully.  Consider a simpler condition: `if (yn != 'y' || yn != 'Y')`.  If the value in `yn` is `y`, the first term is false but the second is true, so the overall result is true; if the value in `yn` is `Y`, the first term is true, so the second is not evaluated and the overall result is true; if the value in `yn` is neither `y` nor `Y`, the first term is true, the second term is not evaluated, and the result is true.

Comment: If you were trying for the opposite condition, you'd need: `if (yn == 'y' || yn == 'Y')` and that would behave as you want.  Look up De Morgan's theorems — `!(A && B) <==> (!A || !B)` and `!(A || B) <==> (!A && !B)` unless I'm misremembering or mistranscribing.  Note that common-place English language usage tends to be a bit sloppy in these situations and can easily lead to confusion when working with formal logical conditions.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Oh! I see now. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: As I was making comments, comments were made before I sent mine. So I figured out the reasoning behind this issue when Jonathan Leffler first notified me.

Comment: @NAE, The logical reasoning is if you use `||` operator, you are checking if the variable does not take "one" of the values listed, which is always true. This is because, the variable is checked against multiple values, one of which is definitely not going to be equal to the variable.

Comment: @user1969104 I see that now; it just took a little bit before I actually figured out your reasoning. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't that be `&&` and not `||`?

```
while(yN != 'y' && yN != 'Y' && yN != 'n' && yN != 'N')
{
    printf("%c\n", yN);
    scanf(" %c", &yN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    while(yN != 'y' || yN != 'Y' || yN != 'n' || yN != 'N')
    {
        scanf(" %c", &yN);
    }
```

the while condition will always return true, and the code won't step out while loop.

Comment: The diagnosis is correct.  What's the prescription for curing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you initialized `yN = 'a'`. So the condition expression `yN != 'y' || yN != 'Y' || yN != 'n' || yN != 'N'` is always true.

```
while(yN != 'y' || yN != 'Y' || yN != 'n' || yN != 'N')
        {
            scanf(" %c", &yN);
        }
```

Comment: the initial value of `yN` being set to 'a' just means the loop will be entered the first time,  Which is what is needed.    Thereafter, `yN` will be what ever was input by the call to `scanf()`

Comment: Thanks! I just found out that the problem is on the condition expression `yN != 'y' || yN != 'Y' || yN != 'n' || yN != 'N'`. `||` must be replaced by `&&`